# HQL with case, sum e max

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a *query* that is giving problem, I believe the problem occurs because it does not allow to use the `max` function, inside the `max` function, am I correct?

How can I get around this? I need to add all values ​​except for the last `row`.

The query:

```
"SELECT new project.domain.vo.MediaPagVo(" +
                    "a.nomeUsuario, " +
                    "a.cpfUsuario, " +
                    "a.cnpjUnidadeUsuario,        " +
                    "a.nomeUnidadeUsuario,        " +
                    "a.codigoGrupoUsuario,        " +
                    "a.grupo.id AS idGrupo,         " +
                    "CASE " +
                        "WHEN MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0 " +
                        "THEN ((MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre)) / SUM(CASE WHEN max(a.dtRequisicao) > a.dtRequisicao THEN a.valorTotal ELSE 0 END)) " +
                        "ELSE ((MAX(a.pos) - MIN(a.pos)) / SUM(CASE WHEN max(a.dtRequisicao) >= a.dtRequisicao THEN a.valorTotal ELSE 0 END)) " +
                    "END AS mediaConsumo, " +
                    "CASE " +
                        "WHEN MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0 " +
                        "THEN " + Tipo.PRE.getValue() + " " +
                        "ELSE " + Tipo.POS.getValue() + " " +
                    "END AS tipoPag) " +
            "FROM " +
                    " Pagamento a " +
            "WHERE " +
                    "a.status = " + StatusPagamento.Concluido.getValue() + " AND " +
                    "a.dataRequisicao BETWEEN :inicio and :fim AND " +
                    "( :idGrupo IS NULL OR a.grupo.id = :idGrupo) " +
                   "GROUP BY " +
                    " a.nomeUsuario, a.cpfUsuario, a.cnpjUnidadeUsuario, a.nomeUnidadeUsuario, a.codigoGrupoUsuario, a.grupo.id, " +
            "HAVING (MAX(a.pos) - MIN(a.pos) > 0 OR MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0) AND " +
                    "( :tipoConsumo IS NULL OR " +
                        ":tipoConsumo = " + Tipo.PRE.getValue() + " AND " +
                        "(MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0) " +
                        "OR :tipoConsumo = " + Tipo.POS.getValue() + " AND " +
                        "(MAX(a.pos) - MIN(a.pos) > 0) ) ";
```

The error began to occur after I modified this section, adding the `case` inside the `sum`:

```
"CASE WHEN MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre) > 0 " +
                        "THEN ((MAX(a.pre) - MIN(a.pre)) / SUM(CASE WHEN max(a.dtRequisicao) > a.dtRequisicao THEN a.valorTotal ELSE 0 END)) " +
                        "ELSE ((MAX(a.pos) - MIN(a.pos)) / SUM(CASE WHEN max(a.dtRequisicao) >= a.dtRequisicao THEN a.valorTotal ELSE 0 END)) " +
                    "END AS mediaPag, "
```

The error returned by java:

`Could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

`ORA-00937: not a single-group group function tips`

My goal was to add up all the payments for that period, minus the last. Unfortunately, I could not just move the filter, since `max (a.pre), max (a.pos)` may be the last payment. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This query will be a nightmare to maintain in the future, you already have problems with it. Instead of doing everything in one query, could you have intermediate steps, like 2-3 queries?

Comment: the future is today... I'm servicing a legacy code. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is also worth asking how to refactor this query. Is performance a problem? I mean instead of running one query you would run several smaller ones would the system be very slow.

For ex. get `MIN MAX(a.pre)` in a separate query, do the `SUM(CASE WHEN` in Java code and pass these values as parameters.

If you decide to refactor, it would be safe to first add some tests to see the behaviour of the old query with certain values. Then do the refactoring. And finally, re-run the tests you added to check that you didn't add any bug.

Comment: The solution was refactor. That query was being very problematic.